# Blackberry application description text error for more than 255 characters

Tags: blackberry

I am using the BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.1.2.201004161203-16 (BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0). Previously i had used the BlackBerry JDE as i shifted to Eclipse plugin since BB JDE is not supporting on importing the external jars to project and creation of single cod for same.

So I have imported my BB JDE 5.0.0 proj to Eclipse plugin using Blackberry Legacy project it successfully imported but it gives error in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml at Application Description.

What i noticed:
If Application description text length more 255 it gives error. If app description is less than or equal to 255 then it doesn't gives an error. My app description is upto 288.
The same thing works in BB JDE.

Can any one help me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but my guess would be that you view the App Descriptor, click on "Internationalized resource bundle available", and set the "Description ID" to a description you have in your localization file.

Note: This only applies to the visual app descriptor.  If you're actually editing the XML then I would recommend switching to the visual view.

Comment: Thanks jonathan for your reply, I have tried what u have suggested but it had not helped. After doing this r the results. 1. In device application Description shows "Unavailable" 2. In BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file Description="" 3. In JAD MIDlet-Description is missing. 4. In ALX Description is black. Any more suggestions r appreciated